# How to add validation for a field with it to be a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and hyphen (-)?

Tags: jquery

I am trying add validation to a field using jquery

i have tried

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}(\.(com|net))?$/;
var domain = 'abc.com';
if(pattern.test(domain)) {
    // valid...
}
```

But this don't work on "-abc.com" as it gets true.

I wanted
**The domain name should be a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and hyphen (-)
& The domain name should not start or end with a hyphen(-)**
& no other validation except this.

Any thoughts ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `\-` from `/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(\.(com|net))?$/`

**Demo**

```js
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\-].*/;
var domain = 'abc.com';
var falsedomain = "-abc.com";
var domain2 = "a-bc.com";
console.log(domain, pattern.test(domain))
console.log(domain2, pattern.test(domain2))
console.log(falsedomain, pattern.test(falsedomain))
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer, how could i remove .com .net validation also ? +1 for answer

Comment: It shows "a-bc.com" as "false", well that's not what i'd like to have.

Comment: I wanted The domain name should be a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and hyphen (-) & The domain name should not start or end with a hyphen(-) & no other validation except this.

Comment: @Developer try and look at the demo

Comment: Thankyou, Sure let me quick test.

Comment: Hello Carsten,sorry but var domain = 'aAbc-.com'; gets TRUE.

Comment: The domain name should be a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and hyphen (-) & The domain name should not start or end with a hyphen(-)

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 1):

The reason your regex fails is because `^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}` means

- `^` must begin with
- a →    Z or a `-`
- `{3,}` 3 or more characters long

So if it starts with a `-` and is 3 chars long, it matches.

```js
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}/.test('abc-'))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}/.test('ab-c'))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}/.test('a-bc'))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z\-]{3,}/.test('-abc'))
```

---

You can create a more 'complex' regex to match it better: `^[a-zA-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\-]{2,}`

- `^[a-zA-Z]{1,}` Must begin (`^`) a→Z, 1 or more chars
- followed by `[a-zA-Z\-]{2,}`, a→Z or `-`, 2 or more chars

```js
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\-]{2,}/.test('abc-'))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\-]{2,}/.test('ab-c'))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\-]{2,}/.test('a-bc'))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z\-]{2,}/.test('-abc'))
```

---

PS: you can make it a little easier on yourself by either lowercasing the input, or making the regex not care, then simplefying the regex groups:

```js
console.log(/^[a-z]{1,}[a-z\-]{2,}/i.test('abc'))
console.log(/^[a-z]{1,}[a-z\-]{2,}/i.test('ABC'))
console.log(/^[a-z]{1,}[a-z\-]{2,}/.test('abc'.toLowerCase()))
console.log(/^[a-z]{1,}[a-z\-]{2,}/.test('ABC'.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: Great explanation, would you prefer adding an expression based on the domain name should be a-z or A-Z or 0-9 and hyphen (-) & The domain name should not start or end with a hyphen(-)  ?

Comment: That would be the same logic as making sure it doesnt start with it, but now at the end :)

Comment: I need make sure hypen should not exist at the end of url & start also.

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my previous comment, I showed the trick how to make sure the start isnt a hyphen, you can do the same for the end :) This website expects some effort from the topic starters :)